# My Ubuntu drive is running out of space, how to fix, something is wrong

Tags: partitioning, files

I'm moving from windows and am having trouble figuring this out:

I'm getting a message that pops up saying disk space is low. It says I have 800MB free. I click on the disk usage analyzer and it shows 24.6 total capacity and 22.5 used.

When I look in GParted it shows a partition  at 72.6GB where I have Ubuntu installed. It also shows that 70.65GB used and 1.94 free in that partition.

How do I figure out what else is in that partition? It's the only ext4 format.

What am I missing?

Comment: We need more info. Are you using a seperate home part? What are the outputs of these commands: `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount` Add those to your question please.

Comment: Instead of `mount` output, `df -h` will be more useful.

Comment: @jamie-flores I suppose you installed Ubuntu inside Windows? That normally happens when you only allocate a few Gigabytes during installation via Wubi. The files accessed in Ubuntu are stored in the Ubuntu virtual partition created during the installation. If you totally want to move to Ubuntu, we suggest you backup all your files first, then proceed with the guided installation.

Comment: Here is what I get back. I have two drives. The first (500GB) is my storage drive. That's in two partitions:

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb445e1d1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   771968739   385983346    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       771971072   976771071   102400000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1549f232

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   307202047   153600992+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       307211119   488375999    90582440+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       459466752   467890175     4211712   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       467893188   488375999    10241406    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb7       307211121   459458999    76123939+  83  Linux

Comment: Above is the OS drive. I have several partitions here. One is for 146GB and that holds Vista, another is for 9.77GB and that is for Windows7, one is the swap drive for Linux that is 4GB, and the last is 72.6GB and that is for Linux (sdb7) that is the one I'm confused about. The disk usage analyzer shows Linux is 24.6GB but GParted shows that partition is 72.6GB big with 70.6GB used. I don't know what is going on with the other 40GB.

Comment: Here's df -h:  Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb7              23G   21G  802M  97% /
udev                 1000M  4.0K 1000M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 403M  936K  402M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                 1007M  132K 1007M   1% /run/shm

Answer (score 1):

Still confused about the directories and drives. I ended up reinstalling Linux in 3 newly configured partitions: home=the documents folder, /= for the OS, and Swap= for the swap file (page file in windows). With this setup I can reinstall Linux without losing my documents: [Partitioning your disks.](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/switching/installing-partitioning.html)

Comment: If re-installing ubuntu solved your problem you should accept your answer or ask to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wipe it your hard disk first using Darik Boot and Nuke or any software that have function like it..

Then, try to install Ubuntu it.